# Drools on web application

Tags: java, spring, drools

I'm very new to drools but I want to integrate it on my existing project. I'm using Spring MVC framework. I successfully implemented the simple example hello world from the free project of drools. What I want to do now is:

1. Send a bean to the rules for it to evaluate.
2. Modify the bean depending on the rules
3. Send it back to the controller to make a response to the user.

The **step 1** I'm already done with it. I was able to insert the bean in rules. What I have for now in my rules is something like this:

```
global String $test;

rule "Excellent"

    when
        $m: FLTBean ( listeningScore > 85 )
        $p: FLTBean ( listeningScore < 101 )
    then
        $test = "Excellent";
        System.out.println( $test );

end
```

For **step 2** and **step 3** I don't know how can I do that. If possible please give me a simple code to be able to do this. I want to have nested rules. With 2 nested rules as an example would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't want to persist the bean? If yes, you should look at kstore.

Comment: @zenbeni Thanks for reply. Could you please give a simple example of how can I do that.

Comment: fyi - I suspect that your rule LHS should be $m: FLTBean (listeningScore > 85, listeningScore < 101) ... that would give you activations for a bean which is between those two values. Your rule is matching 2 FLTBean facts, one of which has a score > 85 and the other of which has a score < 101

Comment: alternatively: (listeningScore > 85 && listeningScore < 101)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to write a query for the bean in order to get it back from the rule engine once the rules have been executed. This could become cumbersome if you have a lot of beans to fetch. [The docs show you an examples of this approach](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch04.html#d0e7632).

Another option could be to have global collection where you collect all the beans at the end of rule execution. Just make sure to have the "collect" rule to be low salience, so that it'll be last to execute. This rule would be something like below

```
rule 'collect results'
  salience -500
  when
    $beans : ArrayList() from collect( MyBean() )
  then
    someGlobal.setBeans( $beans);
end
```

In fact, you can probably add directly to a global List if you want. You can also add some conditions with the `collect` if you don't want all the beans.

Comment: Can you also add how can I collect the beans on the 2nd option you posted?

Comment: @newbie please check the link to Drools documentation. There's a simple example on how to write a query rule and in addition how to call it on the Java side.

Comment: What I mean is the second option you said. Setting a global collection.

Comment: @newbie that's what the example rule is all about. When you you create the Rule Session, you'll have to pass the global object to it. Check out the [bottom of this page](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch05.html), for an example on how to use globals in your rules.

Comment: I see. One last question before I accept your answer. My project is something like a grading system. My approach is to have the java code to check if the answer is correct then the rule engine is the one will be responsible for the grading and tell if what is the user knowledge level. Is my approach proper?

Comment: Sounds all good. Depends on how you check the correctness of the answer, but you could also do this with the rule engine and have the Java app only responsible for handling the request and rendering the response based on the rule engine results.

Comment: If I make the rule engine to check the correctness of the answer, so basically all I have to do is put it on a bean ( or I can send it to the rule even without the bean? ) then send it out to the rule engine to check then query it as you said before then send it back to the view? Am I correct?

Comment: Perhaps you should start another question on this matter with all the relevant information, as it's getting off topic quite badly. Basically, it's all about how you define your fact domain model.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can do this, depending on whether you are using a stateless or stateful session.

```
rule "Excellent"
    no-loop
when
    $m: FLTBean ( listeningScore > 85 && listeningScore < 101 )
then
    $m.setRating("Excellent")
    update( $m )
end
```

In which case your Java code for a stateless session could be:

```
FLTBean flt = new FLTBean(); 
flt.setScore(91);
List<Object> facts = new ArrayList<Object>();
facts.add(flt);
ksession.execute(facts);
System.out.println("Result is " + flt.getRating());
```

If you are using a stateful session then you can insert facts, fire rules and then query facts out of the working memory. Your rule can insert new facts into the working memory like so:

```
rule "Excellent"
when
    $m: FLTBean ( listeningScore > 85 && listeningScore < 101 )
then
    insert( new FLTResult("Excellent") )
end
```

To get the result back out again, you can use the Drools API to find any objects in the working memory.

```
/** Provide a reference to the session and the class name 
 * of the fact you are searching for.
 */
public Collection<Object> findFacts(final StatefulKnowledgeSession session,
        final String factClass) {

    ObjectFilter filter = new ObjectFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(Object object) {
            return object.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(factClass);
        }
    };

    Collection<Object> results = session.getObjects(filter);
    return results;
}

// And call that like so:
FLTBean flt = new FLTBean(); 
flt.setScore(91);
ksession.insert(flt);
ksession.fireAllRules();
results = findFacts(ksession, "FLTResult");
```

Comment: Steve I have a question about this line `insert( new FLTResult("Excellent") )` can I instead do this `insert( FLTBean.setRating("Excellent") )` ?

Comment: No, but you can do: FLTResult fltr = new FLTResult(); fltr.setRating("Excellent"); insert(fltr); It's just whatever Java code you need to create an instance of your class, followed by an insert(...) which puts it into working memory so that rules can act upon it.

Comment: @newbie in situation like yours, I have used static factory methods where you define a static method inside your fact class to return a wanted instance of the class. With this you can make your rules more readable, in this case something like `insert( FLTBean.newExcellentRating() )`. The static method would then return a FLTBean instance where the rating is set to "Excellent". Hope you get the point from this short comment.

Comment: And please note that in @Steve's answer there were two facts in the rule, the bean and result object. You can modify the bean with `modify` instead of inserting a new fact, but as Steve kind of points out, it's probably better to have different objects for the two concepts( answer and rating).

Comment: @JAndy What do you mean by **fact class**?

Comment: @Steve I tried this to get the facts `Collection<Object> result = findFacts( ksession, "com.neu.als.thesis.db.beans.StudentBean" );` then using `for-loop` I tried to print the object or check if it not null. Seems the code doesn't print anything. What am I missing?

Comment: Just use "StudentBean" for that example. Or change it to take Class as an argument and compare to getClass().

Comment: btw - I have fixed the example above to reflect that

Comment: @newbie: fact class == domain class == bean